# Как правильно структурировать mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Делаю сайт, на котором буду получать от пользователей информацию о их местожительстве. Работаю на MeteorJS поэтому база данных используется mongodb. Как правильно будет структурировать коллекцию: создать один объект, в котором сделать структуру Страна -> Город -> Пользователь? или просто добавлять в коллекцию каждого нового пользователя как отдельный объект? Либо возможно есть лучший способ организовать это? Если будет пользователей (к примеру) миллион, нужно, чтобы поиск осуществлялся максимально быстро. Будут такие запросы, в которых нужно будет пройти по всем пользователям и найти поле (например мыло). Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB быстро извлекает данные. Храните в профиле пользователя страну и город. Желательно [создать индекс](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/) для поля «страна» и «город».